# Get identity claims from bearer token (Web API)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, claims-based-identity, bearer-token

I have two Web APIs with a shared machine.key. I would like to pass the bearer token generated by the first Web API to the second Web API as a parameter (i.e. token=xxxxxxxx) and extract the identity claims (i.e userId) from it.

Is this possible? I've looked all over but there doesn't seem to be much information on parsing a text bearer token to extract claims.

Thanks.

Comment: As mentioned below I'm not looking to do anything more with the token then parse it and extract the claims. The second web API itself already has a custom Oauth provider to authenticate callers

Answer (score 1):

If you're using OWIN, you could implement your own `OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider`, which takes the token from the query string and sets it to the context:

```
internal class MyAuthProvider : OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
{
    public override Task RequestToken(OAuthRequestTokenContext context)
        if (context.Token == null)
        {
            var value = context.Request.Query.Get("token");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                context.Token = value;
            }
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}
```

You could use it in your `Startup.cs` like this:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // All the other stuff here

    var audience = "";
    var secret = "...";

    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Provider = new MyAuthProvider(),
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
        AllowedAudiences = new [] { audience },
        IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
        {
            new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider("MyApp", TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(key))
        }
    });

    // All the other stuff here
}
```

When you've implemented your auth like this, you can access the token information in your WebApi controller via the [`User.Identity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.identity(v=vs.110).aspx) property. To read custom claims, you can cast it to [`ClaimsIdentity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsidentity(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
var myClaim = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "myClaimKey");
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm not looking to do anything more with the token then parse it and extract the claims. The second web API itself already has a custom Oauth provider to authenticate users of itself.

Comment: Have you took a a look at [this article](https://shellmonger.com/2015/07/18/decoding-an-auth0-json-web-token-with-c/)? It provides information on how to manually decode a JWT.

Comment: I was wondering, can i access the claims in the Website (frontside) ? which just received the access_token. And can we setup the User.Identity in the website from the token ? So we can use the authentication that has been done server side to regulate access to controllers in Website ?